# What is a word for writing that reveals the author's dialect and/or ideology

Tags: single-word-requests

I am reading an article that is highly ideological, and I am supposed to write a critique of it. I say that it is ideological not because it tries to enforce an opinion, but rather because I can tell from the authors' use of language and dialect what their opinions are (i.e. they use words that are common among certain subcultures and would never be used by members of different cultural/ideological groups). What would should I use to describe writing that is so strongly dialect-based?

Example sentence: "The author's writing was highly ____, I could easily tell what their political, religious, and social views were by analyzing their word choices and dialect."

Comment: *opinionated* is not the same thing as *ideological*. It sounds like you want to say that the article is opinionated. Just because an opinion may differ from your own, that does not make it ideological. Not to mention that neither opinion nor ideology follow from "*dialect-based*". The question sounds confused.

Comment: ..... revealing?

Comment: Somehow I think the term ["shibboleth"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shibboleth) should figure in here.

Comment: Perhaps you should give an example of how you can deduce the speaker's  political, social, and religious views by the use of dialect-based speech. It seems like stereotyping to me.

Comment: This question is difficult to answer because *critique* is used in different ways. A formal, written critique is an unbiased analysis of something, but *critique* is also very often used to mean approximately the opposite - A biased appraisal intended to undermine via fault-finding. Are you looking for a word that connects vocabulary and phrase choice to particular opinions (such as shibboleth), or a rhetorical term for "guilt by association"? Do you want a general term to apply to the entire article's [lexicon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lexicon), or something more granular.

Comment: I wouldn't say that they are necessarily opinionated, and I don't disagree with them. The issue has more to do with word choices that reveal association (though not guilt-by-association). Shibboleth is close to what I mean but I'm looking for a more neutral word (I find Shibboleth is a bit adversarial, and I'm trying to be unbiased).

Comment: *stylistic* : "Of or relating to style, especially literary style." – [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stylistic). Personally, I would misuse (?) *stylized* : "To represent in or make conform to a particular style, especially when highly conventionalized or saliently artistic rather than naturalistic." Except it seems like you want to drop the entire rest of the sentence after the blank? *highly revealing of their heritage* is as close as I can get you on that.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the writing is **idiosyncratic**.

"Idiosyncrasy" per [CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/idiosyncrasy?q=idiosyncratic):

> a strange or unusual habit, way of behaving, or feature:
>   *One of her many idiosyncrasies is always smelling a book before opening it.*

Per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiosyncratic):

> a peculiarity of constitution or temperament :  an individualizing characteristic or quality

In your case, the author's writing is marked by the unique characteristics of the writer.

> The author's writing was highly **idiosyncratic**.

Comment: That has nothing to do with _revealing an opinion or a dialect_, which is the focus of the question. You're describing that the writing is unusual, in a way that the reasoning behind it cannot be understood. Almost by definition, OP is looking for writing where _the reasoning behind it can be understood_ (i.e. OP understands that it is a dialect or an opinion that's leaking).

Comment: +1 This has the right feel for the OP's intent. You might want to use [this](http://www.finedictionary.com/idiosyncratic.html) definition instead, though: *peculiar to the individual "we all have our own idiosyncratic gestures","Michelangelo's highly idiosyncratic style of painting"*.

Answer (score 0):

"The author's writing was highly *characterised*, I could easily tell what their political, religious, and social views were by analyzing their word choices and dialect."

***[Characterise](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/characterised):***

> - to mark or distinguish as a characteristic; be a characteristic of:
>     *Rich metaphors characterize his poetry.*

Also

Connoted,

***[Connote](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/connoted):***

> - to signify or suggest (certain meanings, ideas, etc.) in addition to the explicit or primary meaning:
>     The word “fireplace” often connotes hospitality, warm comfort, etc.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: I am surprised by this use of characterized--as, e.g., more or less expressive of a point of view, suggesting that there is writing free from characterization (or excessive characterization).

Answer (score 0):

I'd call such writing *partisan* or *advocacy*: (both from Google)

par·ti·san
ˈpärdəzən/
noun
noun: partisan; plural noun: partisans; noun: partizan; plural noun: partizans

```
1.
a strong supporter of a party, cause, or person.
synonyms:   supporter, follower, adherent, devotee, champion; More
fanatic, fan, enthusiast, stalwart, zealot, booster
"conservative partisans"
2.
a member of an armed group formed to fight secretly against an occupying force, in particular one operating in enemy-occupied Yugoslavia, Italy, and parts of eastern Europe in World War II.
synonyms:   guerrilla, freedom fighter, resistance fighter, underground fighter, irregular (soldier)
"the partisans opened fire from the woods"
```

adjective
adjective: partisan; adjective: partizan

> ```
> 1.
> prejudiced in favor of a particular cause.
> "newspapers have become increasingly partisan"
> synonyms: biased, prejudiced, one-sided, discriminatory, colored, partial, interested, sectarian, factional
> "partisan attitudes"
> antonyms: unbiased
> ```
>
> ad·vo·ca·cy ˈadvəkəsē/ noun noun: advocacy
>
> ```
> public support for or recommendation of a particular cause or policy.
> "their advocacy of traditional family values"
> synonyms: support for, backing of, promotion of, championing of; argument for, push for;
> informalboosterism of
> "his advocacy of animal rights"
> ```